# Notepad++, Remember previous line folds on startup/file-open?

Tags: notepad++

How do I get Notepad++ to remember previous line folds when I start the program or re-open a file?

Example:

```
//I collapsed/folded my code
[+] My code is collapsed/folded now
 -----------------------------------------

//Closed and re-opened file or Notepad++ 
[-] My code is no longer collapsed/folded, Notepad++ doesn't remember the previous file state
 |  code
 |  code
 |  code
 -----------------------------------------
```

I would like it to behave just like Visual Studio does if possible.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You might want to ask this on the programmers stackexchange. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I flagged it for mod review in-case it doesn't belong here.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I'm actually wrong about this one. Usually questions like these get bombarded with downvotes about how it's not code-related, but in the FAQ it does say "software tools commonly used by programmers" as one of the topics to ask about, so I think you're good. Sorry about that. I'm also interested in this, so I hope someone answers.

Comment: Ahhh k, no problem. Now that I think about it, you're probably right. I've asked a few questions relating to Visual Studio before in the past with no negative effects.